# How to find dynamic element with robotframework?

Tags: robotframework

I have a link: deselect-all
These two links changes dynamically.

```
<span id="deselect-all-8" class="select-all">Tout désélectionner</span>
```

The number 8 changes dynamically after each login.
So how can i find the id or xpath?

I tried this:
xpath=//*[@id="deselect-all"])[1]
link partial= Tout désélec

They cannot find the element.

Example of html snippet:

```
<span id="deselect-all-8" class="select-all">Tout désélectionner</span>
```

Comment: Please provide html snippet that contains desired element.

Comment: <span id="deselect-all-8" class="select-all">Tout désélectionner</span>

Comment: Added snippet to question.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `contains` function in xpath. In your case it would look following:

`xpath=//span[contains(@id, "deselect-all")]`

or you could try find link based on text:

`xpath=//span[text()="Tout désélectionner"]`

Comment: Doesn't works for me. i'm trying to use this ${ordre}    Set Variable    9
    ${ordre}=    Evaluate    ${ordre} - 1    
    ${Num}=    Catenate    SEPARATOR=    //*[@id="deselect-all-${ordre}")]
    ${elementChoisi}    S2L.Get Text    ${Num} it works but the number is always the same i need to increment each time i execute the code.

Comment: I think that my locator return multiple elements and that's why it doesn't work. If my assumption is correct than you need xpath=(//span[contains(@id, "deselect-all")])[${elementChoisi}]

Comment: I feel from my gut feeling that this xpath expression `xpath=//span[text()="Tout désélectionner"]` should works. But the given xpath of course need to be precise starting from root html until span.. for example xpath=//tbody//div[3]/span(text).......